# cambiar el nombre de mi app y luego no funciona

Tags: html, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, windows

Tengo una app, la cual le he cambiado las imagenes y funciona correctamente.

Al cambiar el nombre de la app por medio de res/values/string.xml en el apartado de string app_name (nombre de la app) string lo que sucede es que el NOMBRE SI se cambia, re armo la app, instalo, se abre y en cierto punto SIEMPRE da error 403 y ya no me permite avanzar, si re edito al nombre original puedo volver a usarla.

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="23" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="6.0-2438415" package="com.altared.dvex.clientes" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="28" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:banner="@mipmap/ic_banner" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppThemeOscuro" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.SplashActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@style/AppThemeSplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.MainActivityUt"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.DispositivosActivity"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.LoginActivity"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.RegisterActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:exported="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.MainActivityUi"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.ui.AjustesActivity"/>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.lib.MyFirebaseMessaging">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.altared.dvex.clientes.NetworkReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplayRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.RemoteConfigRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.abt.component.AbtRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        </service>
        <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.extensions" android:required="false"/>
        <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.sidecar" android:required="false"/>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" android:visibleToInstantApps="true"/>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="firebase.auth" android:path="/" android:scheme="genericidp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="firebase.auth" android:path="/" android:scheme="recaptcha"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.altared.dvex.clientes.firebaseinitprovider" android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.altared.dvex.clientes.com.squareup.picasso" android:exported="false" android:name="com.squareup.picasso.PicassoProvider"/>
        <service android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:name="androidx.room.MultiInstanceInvalidationService"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.altared.dvex.clientes.androidx-startup" android:exported="false" android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
        </provider>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery">
            <meta-data android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" android:value="cct"/>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

string

```
 <string name="aceptar_terminos">Debes aceptar los terminos y condiciones</string>
    <string name="add">Add</string>
    <string name="add_a_new_channel">Add a new channel</string>
    <string name="add_channel_manually">Agregar canal manualmente</string>
    <string name="added">added</string>
    <string name="agregar_url">Agregar un link</string>
    <string name="all_channels_removed">La lista ha sido eliminada.</string>
    <string name="all_channels_update">La lista ha sido recargada.</string>
    <string name="already_exists">already exists</string>
    <string name="androidx_startup">androidx.startup</string>
    <string name="app_name">DEVEX</string>
    <string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
    <string name="aspect_ratio_fill">Fill</string>
    <string name="aspect_ratio_fit">Fit</string>
    <string name="bottom_sheet_behavior">com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior</string>
    <string name="bottomsheet_action_expand_halfway">Expand halfway</string>
    <string name="cancel">Cancelar</string>
    <string name="cancel_button_label">Cancel</string>
    <string name="card_content_descriptor">card</string>
    <string name="category_hint">  Category…</string>
    <string name="channel_name_hint">* Channel Name…</string>
    <string name="channel_url_hint">* Channel URL…</string>
    <string name="channels_lower_case">channels</string>
    <string name="character_counter_content_description">Characters
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Como agregas el nombre ? agrega mas información a tu pregunta, revisa [ask],saludos.

Comment: Sin tener mucha experiencia, creo que indicar en detalle el error que encuentras y algún log (el logcat?) va a facilitar el que recibas ayuda.

Comment: @Alfabravo No tengo idea lo que me dices , perdon :( el error es basicamente elegir un usuario de 4 disponibles, al cambiar el nombre no permite elegir y da error 403..

Comment: ¿Si el problema es al cambiar de usuario, en qué afectan los strings? Por cierto, no uses los snippets con XML porque son para HTML, CSS y Javascript.

Comment: @GustavoJavier Creo saber cuál es la causa, especifica el error, que más te muestra además del 403?,  Cuando cambias "app_name" en tu código también se usa este valor, si es así agrega en que se usa.

Comment: @jorgesys no muestra mas nada, cuando le doy a uno de los 4 usuarios se selecciona pero no avanza y sale solo ERROR 403. Pero si del strings vuelvo a poner el nombre original, al elegir el usuario avanza de nuevo. No se a que te referis porque no se de programacion todo esto lo hago de curioso pero necesito hacerlo. Tal vez puedo agregar algun dato mas de los xml mas de lo que estan arriba?

Comment: Para esto se usa el LogCat, ahí se debe desplegar un error que indicaría detalles para solucionar el problema.